# How to rotate a stack of images in 3D space?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, 3d, rotation

I have a stack of 2D images.
lets say below are the dimensions of this volume.

> Depth(Number of images) - 100
> Width(Pixels in X axis) - 200
> Height(Pixels in Y-axis) - 200

I want to rotate this volume and create Bitmaps out of this. I am using `C#` to implement this.

Here is what i did:

```
List<short[]> volumebuffer = new List<short[]>(noImages);
for (int img = 0; imge<noImages; img++)
{

    short[] tmpArray = new short[ImgTotalHeight * ImgTotalWidth];
    int index = 0;
    for (int aHeight = 0; aHeight<ImgTotalHeight; aHeight++)
    {
       for (int aWidth = 0; aWidth<ImgTotalWidth; aWidth++)
       {
           tmpArray[index++] = image[aWidth + aHeight * ImgTotalWidth];

       }
    }
    #append this tmpArray to a List<>
    vomumebuffer.Add(tmpArray);

}
```

In the above code the volumebuffer will contain all the pixel values of all the images. I am converting each short array of each image to byte array and creating the bitmaps out of it.

Now i want to rotate this volume and create bitmaps out of it. I want create only 90 degree orientations.

I tried to read the pixel values in different axis.
Like for reading pixel values in Width-> Depth -> Height order etc..

But this will need many for loops for each orientation.

Is there any better way to achieve orientation of the volume?

Please help me on how i can rotate this volume at 90 degrees in different orientations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? What research have you done? What data structure do you use to represent the volume? Do you want 90-degree rotations or arbitrary rotations? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JonasH - sorry for the vague explanation. I edited the question by providing much information.

Answer (score 0):

you should add methods to index the volume by x,y,z coordinates. Rotation in 90-degrees steps would then simply be switching places of the indices, keeping one dimension fixed. For example

```
bitmap[u, v] = volume[0, v, u]
```

or

```
bitmap[u, v] = volume[v, 0, u]
```

or

```
bitmap[u, v] = volume[xSize - v, u, 0]
```

there should be 24 valid combinations in total

you can replace 0 with whatever valid value you want, and you need to ensure the u/y coordinates are limited to corresponding volume-dimension.

Edit:

Example using multidimensional arrays in order to make indexing clearer. You would need to exchange this with corresponding code, and convert the result to a bitmap.

```
        var volume = new ushort[1, 2, 3];
        var bitmap = new ushort[volume.GetLength(2), volume.GetLength(1)];
        for (int v = 0; v < bitmap.GetLength(1); v++)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < bitmap.GetLength(0); u++)
            {
                bitmap[u, v] = volume[0, v, u];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did not understand your answer clearly. Suppose if i have the volume in x,y,z coords like volume[x,y,z], how can i do a 90 degree orientation and get values to an array ? (using this array i need to create a image bitmap ). Can you please explain me with a sample for loop if possible

Comment: Thank you @Jonash. I will try to do this

Comment: How can we create the arbitrary orientations?

Comment: @Bhargav Sonu Arbitrary rotations are significantly more difficult since it will involve resampling the volume. That is sufficiently different to be a new question.

Comment: For each 90 degree orientations we need to create one for loop combination right. I mean if want 6 orientations do we need to create 6 for loop combinations like the one you mentioned above?

Comment: @Bhargav sonu, that is one way to do it. Another way would be to use a matrix to define the coordinate mapping.